# Como fazer Collapse e Expand de um texto usando apenas HTML5?

Tags: html5, collapse

Escrevi o seguinte código que vi num video tutorial de Bootstrap mas não está a funcionar:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h4><a href="#col3Content" data-toggle="collapse">Column3</a></h4>

  <div id="col3Content" class="collapse">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pancetta  fatback ground round, bresaola strip steak boudin filet mignon turkey kevin drumstick sirloin swine pork belly. Corned beef shankle ham hock drumstick capicola short loin ball tip tri-tip kevin turkey chuck pork belly venison bacon. Fatback turkey swine tongue, chuck jerky doner pork belly pork corned beef rump leberkas. Ham hock fatback bresaola tri-tip salami.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sabes que o Bootstrap tem JavaScript certo?

Comment: Sim mas no video é possivel fazer collapse e expand do texto com apenas estes codigo

Comment: Eu acho que eu já respondi uma que faz isso, mostrar o texto expandido ao clicar (a solução é checkbox se for um item só, e radiobutton se forem vários, mas para mostrar um só por vez). Enquanto não acho o link, segue outra variante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99108/como-clicar-e-descer-uma-parte-oculta

Answer (score 3):

Não estou a ver como isso pode ser feito sem JavaScript. O mais perto é usar o `:active` mas que só funciona no momento em que o mouse é pressionado:

```css
.collapse {
 height: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: height 0.8s;
}

h4:active + .collapse {
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h4><a href="#col3Content" data-toggle="collapse">Faz um clique longo...</a></h4>

  <div id="col3Content" class="collapse">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pancetta  fatback ground round, bresaola strip steak boudin filet mignon turkey kevin drumstick sirloin swine pork belly. Corned beef shankle ham hock drumstick capicola short loin ball tip tri-tip kevin turkey chuck pork belly venison bacon. Fatback turkey swine tongue, chuck jerky doner pork belly pork corned beef rump leberkas. Ham hock fatback bresaola tri-tip salami.</div>

</div>
```

Para fazer isso sem JavaScript podes usar o truque da `checkbox`, que basicamente usa a lógica do `adjacent sibling` no CSS que referi em cima mas usando o estado da `checkbox` como interruptor:

```css
label input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

label h4 {
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.collapse {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.8s;
}

input:checked + .collapse {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <label>
        <h4>Clica aqui</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div id="col3Content" class="collapse">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pancetta fatback ground round, bresaola strip steak boudin filet mignon turkey kevin drumstick sirloin swine pork belly. Corned beef shankle ham hock drumstick capicola short loin ball tip tri-tip kevin turkey chuck pork
            belly venison bacon. Fatback turkey swine tongue, chuck jerky doner pork belly pork corned beef rump leberkas. Ham hock fatback bresaola tri-tip salami.</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Existe ainda uma tecnologia nova no HTML5 que faz isso, sem JavaScript e sem CSS, [usando os elementos `<details>` e `<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details):

```html
<details>
  <summary>Clica aqui...</summary>

  <div id="col3Content" class="collapse">Bacon ipsum dolor amet pancetta fatback ground round, bresaola strip steak boudin filet mignon turkey kevin drumstick sirloin swine pork belly. Corned beef shankle ham hock drumstick capicola short loin ball tip tri-tip kevin turkey chuck pork belly
    venison bacon. Fatback turkey swine tongue, chuck jerky doner pork belly pork corned beef rump leberkas. Ham hock fatback bresaola tri-tip salami.</div>

</details>
```